# is it possible to omit GO in Sybase Sql scripts?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have started doing Sybase programming since some time.the scripts I have encountered are all having GO statements as a batch separator. my question here is is it possible to omit GO in a script and get the script execued? 
if yes, will it affect anything at all ?

Answer (score 0):

`go` is required.  It's no different than Oracle and MySQL using `;`  If you omit the go, the script will not execute.